# Basic option question - spx implied move per day in points

Tags: options

I know that an option implied move per day is vol/sqrt(252).

That being said if I want to convert this in actual SPX points, am I just supposed to multiply this by the forward ? I've been told a 2/sqrt(2*pi) adjustment might be needed but I'm not sure from where this comes from.

Thanks!

Comment: The multiplication by $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ is used to convert a standard deviation to a MAD (mean absolute deviation). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850653/mean-absolute-deviation-of-normal-distribution But usually we work with standard deviations so this conversion is not needed.

Comment: Stock_Price * IV/100 * SQRT(n/365), where n is number of days you are interested in. 365 days because most pricing systems would compute IV that way. Per day is a bit tricky, because you don't have overnight vol. Not in quant se, but you can find, in my biased opinion, a decent explantation [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/155064/109107) on money se. It also explains the MAD mentioned by @nbbo2

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply your volatility number (multiplied by your choice of constant to get an expected daily move - or mean absolute deviation) by the underlying's price.

For the choice of constant, $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ is good enough, especially if you take a short dated ATMF IV which is generally a good predictor of instantaneous vol.